# Routing issues with bonded VLAN trunk bridged to Xen dom0 on CentOS

Tags: centos, xen, vlan, bridge

I am setting up a new dom0 which has a LACP bond. Connectivity is fine between the network, dom0 and domU's without the trunk enabled.

Once I start tagging traffic on the switch and add the respective interfaces (bondX.VLANID and new bridges tied to each VLAN) on the dom0, I encounter two issues.

1. I can only connect to the dom0 via the subnet that the default gateway on the dom0 is set to.
2. All the domU's lose network connectivity (from/to the LAN, dom0, other domU's on the same bridge) regardless of the bridge.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Adding more detail at the request of Tilman Schmidt's comment:

Working:
LACP group on switch -> bond0 (mode 4) on dom0 -> bridge -> domU

Broken:
Trunked LACP group on switch -> bond0 (mode 4) on dom0 with bond0.VLANIDX -> bridgeX -> domU

Connectivity to the dom0 on VLANID X, where the dom0's default gateway is set on VLANID X, works fine but any other VLAN setup does not appear to function even though the interface counters on both the bond0.X and respective bridge increment.

Outside of the standard configuration for bond0, which had no issues until the VLAN's were added, I am adding the following parameters to each bond0.VLANIDX network-script (removing the BRIDGE= line from the master bond0 interface):

```
VLAN=yes
BRIDGE=bridgeX
```

Then, for each bridgeX, I am adding the respective IP information for the VLAN in the IPADDRESS and NETMASK parameters.

Comment: Please provide your complete bonding, VLAN and bridging configuration as well as intended network routing topology. From what you wrote so far, everything is working as it should.

Comment: I just added more detail in the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail. IIUC you are converting the bond interface from a single untagged VLAN into a trunk with several tagged VLANs (including the one that was originally untagged), and getting connectivity over the VLAN that corresponds to the originally untagged one but not over the additional ones. What I'm still unclear about is: What are you expecting to get connectivity to? Are there gateways and/or other hosts in those other VLANs, and where are they located in terms of network topology?